# Lost key to Dell server casing

Tags: keys

I lost the key to remove the casing on my Dell T710 Server.  Where can I get a replacement key?

Comment: try calling dell?

Comment: Ah - DELL? How hard is it to try the company that has it's name written on it?

Comment: Really?  I would try asking the support staff over at Joe's Tackle and Bait store on route 23.  No wait, that's for when I need a lure or some bait.  Maybe Dell would know about how to get replacement Dell hardware, though. :/

Comment: @TomTom, Classic. To Dell with 'em.

Comment: Buy a new T710 server.  They come with the key.  Then use that key to open your existing server.

Comment: Just force a big screw driver in the hole and apply a lot of torque.  Most of the locks are cheaply made and can usually be forced quite easily.

Answer (score 2):

A locksmith should be able to make one for you.

Comment: Probably overkill.  IIRC, they're still using the cylinder locks that can be defeated with a 69 cent Bic pen.  Of course, that would involve walking to the office supply closet, so I'd probably take the path of least resistance and kick the bezel until it popped off, or broke in two.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I don't think this was a serious suggestion :)

Comment: Actually a locksmith should be able to make one for you, or you can learn to do it yourself.

However for security reasons, you may want to replace the lock since you dont know where the original keys are.

Comment: @MDMarra:  Well, we can certainly hope and pray that's the case... but on the other hand, I did have a boss once who chewed out a colleague who lost one of those bezel-lock keys, because that meant he'd have to get a locksmith out to make a key for one of those locks.  :/  And based on the question actually being asked, you have to wonder how many other people would consider this a reasonable solution. :/  Answer definitely deserves a +1, funny, but based on my experience, I feel compelled to... mention other options.  That old boss asshat still works as an IT Operations manager, I'm told.

Comment: @ponsfonze: :/  Actually, you shouldn't rely on those cheap locks for security at all.  I was dead serious when I said you can open them with a Bic pen.  Or a kick.  Or yanking on them too hard.  Instead of replacing the lock for a lost key, anyone relying on those locks for physical security should be replaced instead.  (I can see a very few edge-case type of applications, but it's not security if you can defeat it with your boot.  Or a 69 cent plastic cylinder.)

Comment: Yeah you're right, you probably shouldn't rely on locks at all.  Just leave them off.  Probably shouldn't even lock the server room either because it could just be lock picked as well.  The better way would be to install 3 way authentication to make sure a bic pen wont open it up.  Actually I just started playing this game called Payday: Heist.  In it you act as a bank robber and on the first level you use thermite to burn a hole through the roof of the vault to get to the money.  So I guess we don't even need physical walls at this point because we can just burn a hole into the server room.